# Getting data from listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created listview in C# and filled it with data from SQL server. But when I assign mouse double click, I don't know how to get clicked data. Please help:

My XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewEmployeeDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}" Margin="0,0,0,67" MouseDoubleClick="ListViewEmployeeDetails_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="white" Offset="0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ListView.Background>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Číslo bytu" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=cislo_Bytu}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Podlaží" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=podlazi}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Účel" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ucel}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Width="70" Header="Plocha" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=plocha}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Stav" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=stav}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="70" Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Country}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

String str = "SELECT cislo_Bytu, podlazi, ucel, plocha, stav, poznamky FROM prostory";
cmd.CommandText = str;
ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
cmd.Connection = datovéPřipojení;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds);

ListViewEmployeeDetails.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
datovéPřipojení.Close();
```

So my question is, what I should write into the

```
private void ListViewEmployeeDetails_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Here
}
```

To get the data (`cislo_Bytu`) from the row which was clicked on?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The sender will be the ListView.

```
((ListView)sender).SelectedItem
```

Since you are binding to a `DataView`, the `SelectedItem` will be of type `DataRowView`.  You can then reference the relevant value using the column name.  For example, to assign the value of the `cislo_bytu` column to the `textBox1.Text` property, do the following:

```
textBox1.Text = ((DataRowView)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem)["cislo_bytu"].ToString();
```

Comment: And if I would like to put that data into textbox? the point is that someone will click on the row and text from one cell (for example cislo_bytu) is going to be shown in a textbox... ? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is [OriginalSource MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx)

```
e.OriginalSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get the each item by changing the index value in the ItemArray in your double click event

```
((System.Data.DataRowView)(ListViewEmployeeDetails.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0]
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the object that is selected to access each proprety..

Example:

```
((Class)listView1.SelectedItem).cislo_bytu
```

just change Class to your original class that has proprety cislo_bytu